# Naming variables in dynamically typed languages (such as Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

Say I have a variable `patients`. It could represent the number of patients (an `Integer`), a collection of patient objects (`Patient` class), an array of strings, or a hash.

Sometimes I need a simple count, but `number_of_patients` seems too wordy.  `patients_number` is ambiguous because it could represent a patient's ID or the number of patients. Substituting `count` for `number` is a little better, but doesn't always fit the context.

This problem is worse in Rails because of the convention of using plurals for collections. It feels wrong to use a plural noun to represent an `Integer`. The problem extends from the view to the model, because models often need attributes to count things, plus they may have associated collections (e.g. a `report` has `documents` representing `Document` objects, a field called `diseases` representing an `Array`, and a field called `evaluated` representing an `Integer`).

Are there any conventions for handling these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `patients_count` because that's what ActiveRecord uses when `:counter_cache => true` is given to `belongs_to`, for example:

```
class Patient
  belongs_to :hospital, :counter_cache => true
end
```

would try to increment `hospital.patients_count` every time an associated Patient was added to the Hospital. ([Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to))

Answer (score 2):

There are many conventions, I'd confess to not necessarily knowing the Rails idiom, but...

The number of patients would always be called `numPatients` or `num_patients` (depending on language idiom) by me.

An array / hash / collection of patients would most likely be called `patients`.

YMMV

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of plurality rarely matters, because you iterate over enumerables the same way regardless of the backing class. Counts/sizes of things should be named in a way that identifies them as such--`patients` is what it says, patients, whereas num_patients/etc. represents the count.